# Java convert long day name to short name

Tags: java

I got a day name as string like `Monday`, `Tuesday` or any week day name. but I want to display it as a short day format. like `Mon`, `Tue` and so on. Is there any proper way to do this?. Remember day name is a String. not a Date or Calendar.

Comment: Does this need to be internationalized? You could fairly easily build a `Map<String, String>` for any given locale... just format any 7 consecutive days with `EEEE` and `EEE`  and build the map using the results as the key/value pairs...

Comment: Create a properties file where you keep such mapping and then get the values from properties file, this will allow you to modify the values without changing your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `Map<>` or @Zorian's `String.substring()` are the best ways, another less efficient yet courious way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E");

System.out.println(">>> "  + sdf2.format(sdf.parse("Monday")));
```

Comment: Actually this is a proper way. If I am not wrong this will support internationalization also.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `String.substring(0,3);`?
Through using substring, you get as result the first 3 chars out of your string:
`Monday.substring(0,3);` results in `Mon`